# Logic in React component not working until button in other component was clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to build a component that will display a progress bar at the top of a component that is being wrapped by it and I can not figure out why it is not active until I click one of the buttons rendered by `Pagination` component. The code is:

```
export class IntersectionHandler {
  element: HTMLElement;
  observer: IntersectionObserver;
  listener: void;
  actualState: {
    progress: 0;
    isIntersecting: false;
  };

  constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
    this.element = element;
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(this.handleObserver);
    this.listener = document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
    this.actualState = {
      progress: 0,
      isIntersecting: false,
    };
  }

  private handleObserver(entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) {
    console.log(entries);
  }

  private startListeningScroll() {}
  onScroll() {
    console.log('ev', window.screenY);
    console.log('ev', window.scrollY);
  }
  private onIntersect() {}
}

const WithPogressBar: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const triggerEl = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  if (triggerEl.current) {
    const ih = new IntersectionHandler(triggerEl.current);
    ih.onScroll();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="progress_bar" />
      <div ref={triggerEl}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, actions] = usePagination(mockData);
  const { paginatedChunk } = state;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Pagination state={state} actions={actions} />
      <div style={{ height: '1000px' }}>dfsdf</div>
      <WithPogressBar>
        <PaginatedTable {...paginatedChunk} />
      </WithPogressBar>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

As you can see I have `PaginatedTable` wrapped by `WithProgressBar` and I log to the console some data in `WithProgressBar` component, but nothing is being logged until I click on the `Pagination` component's button, and when I click it, the first value is being logged three times.

Could someone explain me why it is happening and what should I do to have my progress bar working straight a way on page load without user clicking anything?

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing the initial active index in your pagination component?

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks for reply, I pass only last page index to generate proper amount of buttons, is there special prop to tell React that he should be reacting on page load? I can pass it because i export it from hook as well but i don't know how should I implement it

Comment: There is no special prop but you can use hooks for the functional component to update the state on various life stages of the component, same can be done using lifecycle methods for the class component, or you can use event listeners. But for pagination, you just have to work on an array of indexes. Like initial active index will be 0, then on click of button you can move to that index.